# How to get the geolocation location with best accuracy in iOS?

Tags: ios, gps, geolocation

I am using CLLocationManager to retrieve user's current location.It seems that the retrieved location is around 2000 feet away from the actual location. I have set the "**DesiredAccuracy**" to "**kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters**" but it didn't helped.

I thing, the device might have accessed location from the network provider.
I have also tried by adding "gps" in  "UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities" in plist.
But it also giving a far location from the actual one.

So is there any way to retrieve the current position **only with** **GPS Satellites**?

Comment: Are you indoors or outdoors? In a city with tall buildings or in an open space?  GPS signals are affected by buildings - particularly tall buildings that reflect the signal and cause errors in position.  If you are outside in an open space you will get the best positional accuracy.  WiFi location can also help indoors or in city areas

Comment: AFAIK, you can't specify a specific provider (gps/wifi/network) to CLLocationManager. if you set kCLLocationAccuracyBest in DesiredAccuracy the gps chip is supposed to be used to acquire location. actually the gps supposably is used in all DesiredAccuracy under kCLLocationAccuracyThreeKilometers

Comment: We are getting a nearest location in clear sky. but problem happens in indoors. I know that GPS access is not available in indoors and what I am trying to achieve is "to get accurate data (around 50-90 feet accuracy) else no location data and not to get any wrong data" (That's our requirement)

Also I would like to know that which accuracy is better, Horizontal accuracy or vertical accuracy ?

Comment: Vertical accuracy is for altitudes and its used for 3D locations. I dont think you would need that. Also were you able to solve this issue? If yes please let me know

Comment: Yes,I have solved this issue by checking the horizontal accuracy within a desired range. Now it is working fine.